# eclipse product invocation causes ClassNotFoundException of org.eclipse.swt.SWTError

Tags: eclipse, product, classnotfoundexception

I found a nice todo-tool that is based on eclipse-rcp and xtext [(Sebastian Benz - Eclipse-Task-Editor)](http://sebastianbenz.de/a-simple-text-based-todo-editor-for-eclipse). I cloned the git repository an exported the product. Unfortunately, I'm getting following exception as starting the eclipse product:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.swt.SWTError
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:513)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 43 more
```

The entire stack trace can be found [(here)](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=0932H8S1). I found a guy having the same  [exception](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/171373/) caused by some wrong parameters. I removed all of them but the exception is still present. Do you have a clue what could cause the issue? Thank you!

I use Eclipse Indigo Service Release 1 on Gnome/Linux with the following java version:

```
java version "1.6.0_26"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.1-b02, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe , the application not found the right swt lib in your plugin folder. you need a jar named "org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64_xxxx.jar". you can check it.

Comment: Hallo @Jet Geng, you're right :) I wasn't able to find the mentioned jar in the plugin folder. I searched in the workspace for "swt.gtk" and added at the same place where I found "org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86" the dependency "org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64". Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

I solved the 'same/a similar' problem by editing the root pom.xml like so:

```
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>${tycho-groupid}</groupId>
            <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
            <version>${tycho-version}</version>
            <configuration>
              <resolver>p2</resolver>
              <target>
                <artifact>
                  <groupId>de.sebastianbenz.task.tools</groupId>
                  <artifactId>de.sebastianbenz.task.target</artifactId>
                  <version>${task-editor-version}</version>
                  <classifier>indigo</classifier>
                </artifact>
              </target>
              <ignoreTychoRepositories>true</ignoreTychoRepositories>
              <environments>
    <!-- 
                 <environment>
                  <os>macosx</os>
                  <ws>cocoa</ws>
                  <arch>x86_64</arch>
                </environment>
                <environment>
                  <os>win32</os>
                  <ws>win32</ws>
                  <arch>x86</arch>
                </environment>
                <environment>
                  <os>win32</os>
                  <ws>win32</ws>
                  <arch>x86_64</arch>
                </environment>
                <environment>
                  <os>linux</os>
                  <ws>gtk</ws>
                  <arch>x86</arch>
                </environment>
     -->
                <environment>
                  <os>linux</os>
                  <ws>gtk</ws>
                  <arch>x86_64</arch>
                </environment>
              </environments>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>${tycho-groupid}</groupId>
            <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${tycho-version}</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
```

Comment: Could you add what the solution means? I only see commented-out lines of XML, but what is the purpose of doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Believe it or not, I was able to solve the export problem by simply downloading the same version of Eclipse but from a different mirror - initially I downloaded it from the U of Waterloo and the 2nd time around from the U of Pennsylvania mirror. I backed up the projects before blowing away the previous Eclipse installation and re-imported them on the new instance. The product export worked without a hitch. I am using Eclipse 3.7.2 - Indigo for RAP and RCP developers.